# How come Valentine can return to the same side of The Portal?

Tags: mortal-instruments, shadowhunters

In the movie The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones, on the latter part, when Jace and Clary fight against their father(Valentine), they manage to submerge him to the portal but manages to return on the same side. On the other hand, when Clary submerge herself to the portal, she came to Luke Garroway and never returned to the portal. Now, when Hodge Starkweather got the cup from Clary, Valentine suddenly appear to the portal. My question is:where do Valentine came from before he got the cup? Is there another portal on where he came from?

---

Note that I don't have the book to justify my question. This is based on pure observation.

Comment: Didn't Jace explicitly state that the portal takes you wherever you wish to go the most?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, as soon as Hodge Starkweather got the cup from Clary, Valentine suddenly appear to the portal. Where did he came from? Same portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie gives no explanation of how Valentine did this. So, I'll give a book based answer, along with some mild speculation. In the book, Valentine shows up out of no where thanks to the use of another portal. This makes it appear as if he's showing up out of nowhere. My speculation is that he used another portal in the movie, and just used it to port to the portal in the Institute. If they do make the sequel, the knowledge of multiple portals in the city "may" came to be, or it may not. But, given the knowledge in the book, I think it's safe to believe he used another portal.